# Daisy UI checkbox button component appears as a normal checkbox instead of a button in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am using Daisy UI's checkbox button

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox" className="btn" />
```

But instead of button as shown in documentation - [image]

it appears as a simple checkbox - [image]

Expecting - a togglable checkbox like button but instead got a checkbox

Comment: Your example is straight out of the documentation so it should work, https://play.tailwindcss.com/9iRqVdIJ9S

Do other Daisy elements work?

Comment: @stickyuser yes they do work except the checkbox one